# ReflectionException in Container.php line 749: Class App\Http\Controllers\registration does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am new for laravel 5.3.Now i have created a form and when i submit my form it shows an error like

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 749: Class
>   App\Http\Controllers\registration does not exist

1. in Container.php line 749
2. at ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Http\Controllers\registration')
   in Container.php line 749
3. at Container->build('App\Http\Controllers\registration', array()) in
   Container.php line 644
4. at Container->make('App\Http\Controllers\registration', array()) in
   Application.php line 709
5. at Application->make('App\Http\Controllers\registration') in
   Route.php line 203 at Route->getController() in Route.php line 316
6. at Route->controllerMiddleware() in Route.php line 278
7. at Route->gatherMiddleware() in Router.php line 655
8. at Router->gatherRouteMiddleware(object(Route)) in Router.php line
   635
9. at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in
   Router.php line 618
10. at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
11. at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
12. at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) in
     Pipeline.php line 53
13. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
     CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
14. at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request),
     object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
15. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
     Pipeline.php line 33
16. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
     Pipeline.php line 104
17. at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
18. at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php
     line 117
19. at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
20. at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_demo\public\index.php') in
     server.php line 21

I have a route like

```
Route::resource('registration','RegistrationController');
Route::post('store','registration@store');
```

Here my **RegistrationController** is renamed as **registration**

**My RegistrationController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\RegistrationModel;
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
  public  function index()
  {
     // $uers=DB::table('tset')->get();
      //return $uers;
       return view('pages.registration');
     // return view('pages.registration')->with('users',$uers);  //return users from db
  }

  public function store()
  {

  }
}
```

**My view page:**

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'registration@store', 'method' => 'post'))}}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
           Entr SNO:
        </td>
        <td>
         {!! Form::text('sno', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
          Enter Name:
        </td>
        <td>
         {!! Form::text('sname', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
          Enter Course:
        </td>
        <td>
         {!! Form::text('course', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
           Entr SNO:
        </td>
        <td>
       {{ Form::select('number', [1, 2, 3], null, ['class' => 'field']) }}
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
    {!! Form::submit('Submitform', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I don't know why i get this error when i click on save button for saving a post.Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add new methods to a resource controller by adding a route to that method separately before you register the resource.

So your route should be as: *(Notice the sequence)*

```
Route::post('store','RegistrationController@store');
Route::resource('registration','RegistrationController');
```

And your in your view it should be used as:

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'RegistrationController@store', 'method' => 'post'))}}
```

*Note - Don't rename your `RegistrationController`*

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers)

> If you need to add additional routes to a resource controller beyond
>   the default set of resource routes, you should define those routes
>   before your call to `Route::resource`; otherwise, the routes defined by
>   the resource method may unintentionally take precedence over your
>   supplemental routes.

Comment: Thanks..I have change my form action and its working now

Comment: Glad I could help! :D